# Why is VirtualBox crashing when executing a virtual machine?

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to install and use VirtualBox in a lab with heterogeneous computers. In one machine (with Intel E5500) it works perfectly. In all others (most wwith E2180) it doesn't work. Why is it happening?

All machines have Windows 7 32 bits.

```
Log: https://pastebin.com/nfbPYGP7
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try and modify your settings.

In System /// Acceleration panel look for “enable VT-x”. When enabled your VM will take advantage of the hardware VT-x circuits but it might be the problem for your E2180 as it does not implement this Technology.

[Processor E2180](https://ark.intel.com/products/31733/Intel-Pentium-Processor-E2180-1M-Cache-2_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB) vs
[Processor E5500](https://ark.intel.com/products/42800/Intel-Pentium-Processor-E5500-2M-Cache-2_80-GHz-800-MHz-FSB)

Comment: It was not possible to change it. The acceleration panel is disabled.